# Ajax calls in rails when jquery.js included don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Rails 2.3.8.

In my application.rhtml I have:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.js"%>
```

And in my index.rhtml which uses application.rhtml for a layout I have:

```
<div id="search_residential"> <%= link_to "Residential", 
"javascript:residentialSearchForm()", :onclick=> remote_function(:url => {:propertyType => 'residential', :controller => 'site', :action => 'searchform'}, :update => 'search_form', :method => :get)%></div>`
```

In my partial that should be rendered I have:

```
<%logger.debug "Residential Form Partial Rendered"%>
```

When I click the link my log outputs:

```
Processing SiteController#searchform (for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-05 11:11:02) [GET]
  Parameters: {"controller"=>"site", "propertyType"=>"residential", "action"=>"searchform", "authenticity_token"=>"Iw3ID/4Lh5IReUwOnhhSUXfn2IIVUnYpqG1N7DE4BHg="}
Rendering site/searchform
Residential Form Partial Rendered
Rendered site/searchbar/_search_residential (5.2ms)
Rendered site/searchbar/_search_form (5.9ms)
Completed in 9ms (View: 7, DB: 0) | 200 OK [http://localhost/site/searchform?propertyType=residential&authenticity_token=Iw3ID%2F4Lh5IReUwOnhhSUXfn2IIVUnYpqG1N7DE4BHg%3D]
```

But nothing is shown on the website. If I remove the include for jQuery then the partial is rendered.

Comment: Do you have a Div with id search_form?

Comment: Yea, it's a bit below the where the div I have in the question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remote_function is a prototype helper and depends on prototype.js
Jquery would be conflicting at the $ namespace. Its advisable to not use prototype helpers.
Or You should initialize jquery in a noConflict mode.

Comment: This has helped me to start looking in the right direction and I've now got a solution for my issue, thank you.